# Gulp/Babelify es6

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am using `babel` to transpile my es6 code. I'm also using gulp to do the tasks. My `gulpfile.js` looks like the following :

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    es6Path = './src/*.js',
    browserify = 'browserify',
    babelify = require('babelify'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('build', function () {
    return browserify({entries: './src/script.js', extensions: ['.js'], debug: true})
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['build'], function () {
    gulp.watch(es6Path, ['build']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

But when I try to run gulp , I get this error :

```
Starting 'build'...
'build' errored after 100 μs
TypeError: string is not a function
```

Any idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `browserify` to string `'browserify'` then try to call it as a function. You need to `require('browserify')`.